# android: how to restore android listview state on app launch

Tags: android, listview

how does one save a clicked state in android listview after exiting the app and restore state on app launch.The app should be able to listen to click event on listview and save the state and when the app is closed it saves the clicked state and then restore it on relaunch.
i have tried using getView but it doesnt seem to work as expected. please help

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: i don't understand what you trying to tell pls tell us your code

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? are you trying to save the state of your listview where it left off before you close the app? or you just want to redraw all the view of the listview on app launches? show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is, you have to override the below method in your Activity,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And save the state of your Button using SharedPrefrence, and next time when you enter your Activity get the value from the Sharedpreference and set the enabled state of your button accordingly.

Example,

```
private void SavePreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("state", button.isEnabled());
editor.commit();   // I missed to save the data to preference here,. 
}

private void LoadPreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean  state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state", false);
button.setEnabled(state);
}    
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

    SavePreferences();
    super.onBackPressed();
}



onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

LoadPreferences();
//just a rough sketch of where you should load the data
}
```

Comment: actually what am trying to achieve is, i have a listview so whenever a row is clicked, it should be marked as read and have a different background colour from the rest of the unread(unclicked rows). and when the app is closed and relaunched it should be able to show the read and unread, Do you have any ideas around that

Comment: its just the way the messaging app works or whatsapp, read and unread messages.

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet but will soon :)